# How to check if object is one of union type

Tags: typescript

I have 2 interfaces: `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

My React script receives on object `Object` that has type of `TypeA|TypeB`.

I have a function `doSomething(attribute:TypeA)`
I want to pass an `Object` as an attribute like this `doSomething(Object)`,
but TS says

> Type 'TypeA | TypeB' is not assignable to type 'TypeA'.
>     Type 'TypeB' is missing the following properties from type 'TypeA': prop1, prop2, prop3.

Maybe I can set a new temporary variable only if it's of type `TypeA` and then pass it to the function?

```
const tempVar:Type1 = Object
```

I have tried this

```
const tempVar:Type1 = Object instanceof Type` ? Object : undefined ;
```

but I'm getting this error in addition to the one above

> 'Type1' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Is there a workaround for the situation, since I cannot change the function `doSomething()` to accept both types?

Comment: What features distinguish the two types? In other words, if you were writing pure javascript, what would you check to tell what kind of object you were dealing with?

Comment: @NicholasTower There's a prop called `prop1:string` that I can check:
`
if(Object.prop1 === 'value1'){
  doSomething(Object);
}
`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), and call that to narrow the type. If the function returns true, then typescript knows the object is of the specified type. For example:

```
const isTypeA = (obj: TypeA | TypeB): obj is TypeA => {
  return obj.prop1 === 'value1';
}

// elsewhere:
function somefunction(obj: TypeA | TypeB) {
  if (isTypeA(obj)) {
    // Inside this block typescript knows that obj is a TypeA, and can't be a TypeB
    doSomething(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: If `TypeA | TypeB` is a discriminated union on `prop1`, `obj.prop1 === 'value1'` will work as is to narrow no need for the custom type gurad. If the types in the union have differnt props `in` will probably be simpler to use (`if 'propInA' in obj) { ... obj is TypeA now .. }`

Comment: Is there any way to narrow the type without using a JS predicate function like this? I was thinking somehow using a generic type, like `somefunction<TypeA>` or `somefunction<TypeB>`

Answer (score 12):

One possible solution together with Nicholas Tower [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610115/1768179) is to use `in` keyword.

Copied from [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

```
function move(pet: Fish | Bird) {
  if ("swim" in pet) {
    return pet.swim();
  }
  return pet.fly();
}
```

Comment: This, I would argue, could be even better than Tower's answer in some situations. The problem with the custom type guard is that nothing prevents the programmer of leaving a bug in the comparisson. Using the *in* keyword will have typescript correctly guessing the type or warning you if checking for that property isnt enough.